# Переместить блок div на странице вниз, не изменяя код страницы (в коде оставить сверху)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css3

Я раньше где-то встречала возможность перемещения блока, к примеру, div в рамках страницы, не затрагивая исходный код, но не помню где я это видела. У меня на сайте вышло так, что заголовок h2 располагается ниже, чем h3, а если сделать его выше, то пользователям загораживает пол экрана описание категории. Поэтому вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы в коде страницы описание отображалось сверху страницы, а для пользователя выводилось снизу?

Comment: _"не затрагивая исходный код"_ - попросите его, вдруг поможет

Comment: тут либо разметку менять (или ее генерацию на пхп) либо двигать с помощью js. Второй вариант потенциально может быть заметен глазу пользователя.

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  display: grid;
}
h2 {
  order: 1;
}
h3 {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Заголовок H3</h3>
  <h2>Заголовок H2</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Я вот подумываю над flex order, но есть сложность с размещением всех элементов внутри одного контейнера. А grid страшно использовать, ведь поддержка браузерами еще меньше 90%.

Comment: @user1362765, можно использовать и flex, но нужно учесть что элементы будут сжиматься по горизонтали и вертикали по базовой линии, делаясь резиновыми.

Comment: @user1362765 согласен с вами, `css grid` поддержка браузерами началась только прошлого года. Точнее с версии `Chrome 57` и `Firefox 52`